# Android TextToSpeech fails intermittently

Tags: android, android-emulator, text-to-speech

I am new to Android programming. I am getting helpful tips from this community. Having seen some progress in my work, I getting motivated to do more.

I have a peculiar problem with TTS. At times it fails to work. I observed that if I restart the IDE, it was working. Today in spite restarting couple of times, TTS is not working. I have not done any major changes to the code since I noticed TTS failure. The code is as below

```
package com.example.ptimer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ptimer.databinding.FragmentLauncherBinding;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LauncherFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentLauncherBinding binding;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentLauncherBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {

                // if No error is found then only it will run
                if(i!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    Toast.makeText(LauncherFragment.this.getContext(), "TTS init passed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(LauncherFragment.this.getContext(), "TTS init failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        binding.launcherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textToSpeech.speak("Launched",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null, null);
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(LauncherFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_LauncherFragment_to_ActionFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

As per some posts in this form, I inserted two Toasts to check if TTS initialization is happening properly. As expected I get success message but TTS fails to speak.

My emulator is NEXUS 4 API 22.

Please help me to locate the error.

Comment: TTS initialization may take a while, so if you press `launcherButton` too early it won't speak anything.

Comment: @Markus , today  TTS is working. Let me wait for few seconds before pressing `launcherButton` when I see application failing to speak next time. Thanks

Comment: @Markus, just now I started IDE and TTS failed. I pressed launcherButton after few minutes, but it did not help.